# White page on custom plugin option submit

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, admin-menu

I have a plugin I am designing an admin page for, when I hit submit I get a white page with no errors or text of any kind.

Here is my code

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'linc_plugin_settings' );
add_action('admin_menu', 'linc_plugin_menu');

function linc_plugin_settings() {
    $id = 1;
    $url;
    $input_value = $_POST['urlfield'];
    if(isset($_POST["urlfield"]) && is_array($_POST["urlfield"])){  
    foreach ($input_value as $url) {

    register_setting( 'linc-post-url-' . $id++, $url );
}
    }
}


function linc_plugin_menu() {
    add_menu_page('Linc Post Settings', 'Import Settings', 'administrator', 'linc-post-import-settings', 'linc_plugin_settings_page', 'dashicons-hammer');
}

function linc_plugin_settings_page() {
  ?>
  <div id="content"> 
  <h2 id="header-text" align='center'> Linc Post Importer </h2>
  <h3 id='instructions' align='center'> Enter the URL of the Linc City Site that you wish to import posts from. <br /> Use the import button to run the import function for the newly added URL's</h3>

<h2> Enter URL Below <br /> ex. http://www.linccity.com/</h2>

<form id="url-list">
    <input id="url-field-1" name="urlfield[]" type="text">

<button class="button" id="add-url"> + </button>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("#add-url").click(function(){
            $( "#submit" ).before( "<br  /><input id='url-field-1' name='urlfield[]' type='text'><br  />" );
  });
    });
    </script>
    <?php submit_button(); ?> 
    </form>
  </div>
  <?php
}
```

I am trying to add a setting for each one of the boxes that has a url in it when I submit the form.

Comment: Your form is submitting to admin.php via `GET` method  so you are getting white/ blank page on click of '+' button so update your script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button is submitting the form
use this script

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("#add-url").click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
            $( "#submit" ).before( "<br  /><input id='url-field-1' name='urlfield[]' type='text'><br  />" );
  });
    });
    </script>
```